# how to override cdk-mouse-focused and cdk-focused

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have a 2 mat buttons adjacent.Whenever i click on one, cdk-focused and cdk-mouse-focused class gets applied on that button, However when i click on other button the other button too, gets the same class and both look highlighted.
How can I override these classes so that both buttons don't look highlighted.
I am unable to figure out how to override the cdk-focused and cdk-mouse-focused class.

```
<button aria-haspopup="true" class="my-menu-top-menu mat-button ng-star-inserted " mat-button="" 
ng-reflect-klass="mega-menu-top-menu" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" ng-reflect-menu="[object Object]"><span class="mat-button-wrapper">
Maintenance
 </span><div class="mat-button-ripple mat-ripple" matripple="" ng-reflect-trigger="[object HTMLButtonElement]" ng-reflect-centered="false" ng-reflect-disabled="false"></div><div class="mat-button-focus-overlay"></div></button>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 .mat-button-focus-overlay {
   background-color:transparent !important;
  }
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for trying to answer this question, please try to explain the logic behind your solution.